# SSH: Access local file (redirect local file contents) via remote SSH console

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, redirect

**I want to redirect the output of a local command (using local files) to a remote command.**

---

I know doing something like this is possible:

```
[user@local ~]$ head -c 5 /dev/urandom | ssh server@192.168.1.120 "cat"
```

... but I would like to know if there is a way to do this via the SSH console, just like the `scp` command that refers both local and remote files:

```
[user@remote ~]$ scp test.txt remote:/new.txt
```

---

**Copying the local file to the remote server is undesirable, I would just like to redirect output.**

** *Both machines run Linux (bash).*

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to redirect the output to a file and then scp that file to the remote host and then you can run the cat command there.

`$ head -c 5 /dev/urandom > random && scp ./random user@remoteip:/path/. && cat /path/random`

Hope this will satisfy your needs. Reply if it don't.

Comment: I am upvoting even though the OP said that this isn't what he wants. So long as he doesn't need active streaming (by his example, he doesn't), this should be the most straightforward method.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440524/ssh-a-way-to-transfer-files-without-opening-a-separate-sftp-session

So, it looks like the consensus is to set up an inverted ssh session with the -R option, and run the stdout through that.